# Ассемблер. Массив

Tags: ассемблер

arr dd 4 dup(3, 7, 0)

Что делает эта строчка?
*fasm для windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта строчка объявляет массив c именем *arr*, где *dd* указывает на размерность каждого элемента в 4 байта, число 4 означает максимальную длину, в скобках задается содержание. Если хотите объявить пустой массив для последующего заполнения используйте знак вопроса.

Например, массив из 100 элементов, но без значений:

```
arr dd 100 dup(?);
```

Или массив из 5 нулевых элементов. Размер каждого элемента 2 байта:

```
mas dw 5 dup(0)
```

Шаблон для строки *arr dd 4 dup(3, 7, 0)*:

```
имя массива (arr), размерность ячейки(dd=4байта), количество ячеек(4), содержание dup(3,7,0)
```

Comment: Массив [3, 7, 0, ?] где ? - зарезирвированная переменная. Я верно понял?

И в чем тогда будет разница между 
arr dd 100 dup(?) И
arr rd 100 dup(?) 
или имена массивов нельзя резервировать?

Comment: @neko69, `arr dd 100 dup(?)` эквивалентно `arr rd 100`.

Comment: @neko69, что за rd? Разница между двумя приведенными Вами массивами, если там вместо rd, например dw, что ячейки будет разного размера. Если dd ячейки по 4 байта, а если dw по 2 байта. 

Нет, на сколько мне известно не верно, вопрос используется, если хотите пустой массив объявить и только.

Вы можете зарезервировать почти любое имя для массива, будь-то arr или mas, или любое другое и в последующем проводить с использованием имени массива операции перемещения, удаления элементов и так далее.

Comment: @Ilja, rd (rb, rw, rq) - это reserve dwords (bytes, words, qwords etc.), специфичная для fasm инструкция. Чему она эквивалентна я уже написал. Ссылка на [статью в flat assembler manual](http://www.flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#1.2.2).

Comment: @insolor, аааа... мало я писал на ассемблере.